# ORA-01403: no data found error in businesshr trigger

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

im trying trigger on following tables oracle sqlplus

```
SQL> create table Employees1727
  2  (
  3  emp_id number(4) primary key,
  4  last_name varchar2(15),
  5  first_name varchar2(15),
  6  email varchar2(30),
  7  phone_no varchar2(12),
  8  hire_date date,
  9  job_id varchar2(10), 
 10  salary number(10),
 11  commission_pct number(2,2),
 12  manager_id number(4) references Employees1727(emp_id), 
 13  dept_id number(3)
 14  );
```

Table created.

```
SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> create table Departments1727
  2  (
  3  dept_id number(4),
  4  dept_name varchar2(15),
  5  manager_id number(4) references Employees1727(emp_id), 
  6  loc_id number(4)
  7  );
```

Table created.

```
SQL> create or replace trigger businesshr
  2  before insert or update or delete on Employees1727
  3  for each row
  4  begin
  5  if to_char(sysdate, 'hh24') >= '05' AND
  6     to_char(sysdate, 'hh24') <= '18'
  7  then
  8  select * into 
  9  :new.emp_id,
 10  :new.last_name,
 11  :new.first_name,
 12  :new.email,
 13  :new.phone_no,
 14  :new.hire_date,
 15  :new.job_id, 
 16  :new.salary,
 17  :new.commission_pct,
 18  :new.manager_id, 
 19  :new.dept_id
 20  from Employees1727 ;
 21  else
 22  raise_application_error (-20000, 'Employee info may not be modified at this time!') ;
 23  end if;
 24  end businesshr;
 25  /
```

Trigger created.

```
SQL> insert into Employees1727 values(1,'Patil','Pratik','Pratik@gmail.com',23994723, '12-FEB-2010',101,15000,0,1,2);
insert into Employees1727 values(1,'Patil','Pratik','Pratik@gmail.com',23994723, '12-FEB-2010',101,15000,0,1,2)
        *
```

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-01403: no data found
>   ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.BUSINESSHR", line 5
>   ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.BUSINESSHR'

Comment: Your concern is still not clear...also format the code remove the line no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In trigger you shouldn't select from table on which trigger is operating, because you can get `mutating table` error. In this case no select is needed at all, just write it as here:

```
create or replace trigger businesshr
  before insert or update or delete on Employees1727 
  for each row
  begin
    if to_char(sysdate, 'hh24') < '05' or '18' < to_char(sysdate, 'hh24') then
      raise_application_error (-20000, 'Employee info may not be modified at this time!') ;
    end if;
  end businesshr;
```

Comment: yes but i want to perform operation on  db only on business hr thats why i have to use select into for inserting record in business hours.

Comment: That's what this trigger does. If you try to insert data before or after business hours it will throw error. Otherwise insert will be succesfull.